# Bosun notification URL in subscription

Tags: fiware-bosun

I have fiware-bosun running. I’m trying to create a new rule to send me an email when memory usage is higher than 95% but when I try to subscribe the server to this rule I do not know which notification URL should I have to write in the subscription.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIWARE Bosun is a generic enabler instance which acts as a REST notification service, so it is expected to have another REST service that implements the actions.

In your case, you need a REST service expecting a POST request.

The request will be similar to this one:

```
{"action": "notifyEmail", 
"serverId": "00000000000001", 
"email": "youremail@host.com",
"description": "Memory usage is higher than 95%"}
```

*ServerId* is the OpenStack Id of the server from which you want to check the corresponding rules. Notification URL must be the url of this REST service which is waiting the message to process and send the corresponding email. This service must be implemented by the user.